# Why I use Gunicorn to run Flask app it seems ‘no module named app’

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

Flask app it's ok,but when I use Gunicorn command:

```
gunicorn -w 4 -b 127.0.0.1:8004 app:app
```

or

```
gunicorn -w 4 -b 127.0.0.1:8004 route:app
```

it seems  ImportError: No module named 'app'

my structure

```
app
    │  config.py
    │  data.db
    │  forms.py
    │  models.py
    │  mulu.txt
    │  route.py
    │  __init__.py
    │  templates
    |  static
```

app is defined in **init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
```

route.py

```
from app import app
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'hello world'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Why?Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app instance is defined in `__init__.py`, so you should do

```
gunicorn -w 4 -b 127.0.0.1:8004 __init__:app
```